# Как сделать возможность скролить блок с помощью мыши, не используя скроллбар?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет. Есть вот такой блок:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] скажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы была возможность скролить этот блок при зажатой левой клавиши мыши.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
(function(){
let speed = 2; // Скорость скролла.

let scroll = document.querySelector('.scroll');

let left = 0; // отпустили мышку - сохраняем положение скролла
let drag = false;
let coorX = 0; // нажали мышку - сохраняем координаты.

scroll.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  drag = true;
  coorX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  drag = false;
  left = scroll.scrollLeft;
});
scroll.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (drag) {
    this.scrollLeft = left + (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - coorX)*speed;
  }
});

})();
```

```css
.scroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: orange;
  border-right: 3px solid #045acf;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="block"></div
  ><div class="block"></div
  ><div class="block"></div
  ><div class="block"></div
  ><div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Можно запариться, измерять расстояние между точками нажатия и отпускания, разделить на пройденное время - в зависимости от этого числа поставить setInterval, который по инерции продолжит скроллить несколько миллисекунд.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что нужно.